# Firebase errors since updating pods to Firebase 5.4

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

Any idea's how I can fix the following issues.
I keep getting the error: Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL' and Use of unresolved identifier 'uid' than

```
storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }

                if let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {

                    let values = ["name": name, "email": email, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl]

                    self.registerUserIntoDatabaseWithUID(uid: uid, values: values as [String: AnyObject])
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageMetadata), `metadata` no longer has a `downloadUrl()` function. Instead, you use the `storageRef`, as shown in the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_files):

```
storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
        return
    }

     storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
         guard let url = url, let profileImageUrl = url.absoluteString else { return }
         let values = ["name": name, "email": email, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl]
         self.registerUserIntoDatabaseWithUID(uid: uid, values: values as [String: AnyObject])
    }
}
```

As for `uid`, that's just a variable. Seems like it's something the code would have had to define. Not sure where you had defined it before.

Comment: Now I get the error, "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String' " for the downloadURL part

Comment: Any thoughts on what I could do?